# MemoryError when generating numpy.MultivariateNormal

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with 707 columns and 3947 rows. From this, I calculate a 707x707 covariance matrix, and an array or row means using numpy.cov and pandas.df.mean respectively.

When I use this covariance matrix and set of means to try to generate a random multivariate normal toy dataset using numpy, I get back a MemoryError.

How could I generate a random dataset this large with these specifications without getting this error?

Edit:

Here's my stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-701051dd6b16>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/project/home17/whb17/Documents/project2/scripts/mltest/covex.py', wdir='/project/home17/whb17/Documents/project2/scripts/mltest')

  File "/project/soft/linux64/anaconda/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/project/soft/linux64/anaconda/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/project/home17/whb17/Documents/project2/scripts/mltest/covex.py", line 36, in <module>
    d2_x, d2_y = multivariate_normal(means, X_cov, [n_cols, n_rows], check_valid='ignore').T

  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4538, in mtrand.RandomState.multivariate_normal

MemoryError
```

Edit 2:

And here's the code that causes it:

```
X = pd.read_csv('../../data/mesa/MESA.csv', sep=',', header=None, index_col=0)

n_cols, n_rows = X.shape

means = X.mean(axis=0).tolist()

X_cov = np.cov(X.T)

d2_x, d2_y = multivariate_normal(means, X_cov, [n_cols, n_rows]).T
```

Comment: What command specifically raising the error?

Comment: Also, are you sure the matrix shouldn't be 707 X 707? Usually columns are variables, and rows are instances.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue. I've edited the original post accordingly, but I still have the MemoryError.

Comment: Could you write the exact command + stacktrace that you see? It's possible you're using it the wrong way. These sizes (including the original ones) are just not very large.

Comment: It's in the new edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it seems very likely that you've misinterpreted the use of [`multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.multivariate_normal.html) in

```
d2_x, d2_y = multivariate_normal(means, X_cov, [n_cols, n_rows]).T
```

The first and second parameters here are the means and covariance. The third parameter is the shape of the matrix *every cell of which* should be an instance of the random matrix. This is not something whose transpose is a pair, and is almost certainly not what you want.

Just as an example, if the dimensions of `X_cov` are 707 X 707, then the dimensions of the result are 707 X 707 X 707 X `n_rows`.

To generate a toy dataset, you should use

```
multivariate_normal(means, X_cov, n_rows)
```

The overall result, compared to your original question (before the first edit), should be smaller by about 1 / 1250000.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting `TypeError: 'multivariate_normal_frozen' object is not iterable`

Comment: If you're trying to assign it to a pair, then, yeah - you'll get that error. Each time you call it, it will generate a single dataset with the dimensions of your original one. If you want two, I suggest you call it twice.